# Mongodb geolocation boundaries search/query

Tags: mongodb, geolocation, geospatial, mongodb-query, geojson

I have a documents contains list of location "boxes" (square area). Each box is represented by 2 points (bottom-left or south-west, top-right or north-east).

Document, for example:

```
{
   locations: [
        [[bottom,left],[top,right]],
        [[bottom,left],[top,right]],
        [[bottom,left],[top,right]]
   ]
}
```

I'm using [2d](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/2d/) index for those boundaries points.

My input is a specific location point [x,y] and I want to fetch all documents that have at list one box that this point is located in it.

Is there any [geospatial operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query-geospatial/) I can use to do that?
How do I write this query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the box operator, see:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/box/#op._S_box with the following example taken directly from that page:

```
db.places.find( { loc : { $geoWithin : { $box :
                                      [ [ 0 , 0 ] ,
                                        [ 100 , 100 ] ] } } } )
```

It is worth noting that the 2d index is considered legacy. If you can convert to using GeoJSON and a 2dsphere index, then you can use the $geoWithin operator: see

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/#op._S_geoWithin

GeoJSON has a number of other benefits, not least of which, is that it is easily transmitted and digested by web mapping apps such as OpenLayers or Leaflet.

Comment: Is this really the answer to Op's question? This query finds a location [ lng, lat ] present in a document by passing some bounds as input. But how can it recognise if a [ lng, lat ] passed as input is inside some bounds saved in the document? Or do I misunderstand something here?